# How to access variables in a different class?

Tags: java, variables, bluej

My first class called Match creates an individual soccer/football game. It makes you choose 2 teams and the final score. The second class called "team" is a bit more advanced. When the play (match match) method is called, the number of games played increments by 1. This part works fine. My else if statements for (goalsForThisMatch) also works fine. However, when I inspect the Team class object, it should display the same goals for and goals against that I inputted in the Match class. What actually happens is when I inspect the Team class after pressing the play(Match match) method, most of the methods are set to 0, except the "played" method (which increments by 1 like it's supposed to) and whatever the final score is. So if I inputted the score in the match class so that the home team has scored more goals and has won the match, then the Won method in the object inspector for the Team class will go up by 1. I need two of the other methods in the team class to link with the match class. These methods are: Goals For and Goals Against. If I input the GoalsFor in the match class to be "4" then when I inspect the Team class the goalsFor should be set to 4 also.

I know this all probably sounds VERY confusing, please forgive me, I'm so TIRED I'm about to head off to sleep. Hopefully in the morning, someone would have sorted this issue for me.

```
public class Match

    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private String HomeTeam;
    private String AwayTeam;
    private int HomeGoals;
    private int AwayGoals;


    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Match
     */
    public Match(String ShortHomeTeamName, String ShortAwayTeamName, int NewHomeGoals, int NewAwayGoals)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        HomeTeam = ShortHomeTeamName;
        AwayTeam = ShortAwayTeamName;
        HomeGoals = NewHomeGoals;
        AwayGoals = NewAwayGoals;
    }

        public String getHomeTeamName(){

        return HomeTeam;
    }

        public String getAwayTeamName(){

        return AwayTeam;
    }

        public int getHomeGoals(){

        return HomeGoals;
    }    

        public int getAwayGoals(){

        return AwayGoals;
    }    


}




public class Team 

    private String TeamName;
    private String ShortName;
    private int Played;
    private int GoalsFor;
    private int GoalsAgainst;
    private int GoalDifference;
    private int Won;
    private int Drawn;
    private int Lost;
    private int Points;


    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Team
     */
    public Team(String FullTeamName, String ShortTeamName)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        TeamName = FullTeamName;
        ShortName = ShortTeamName;
        Played = 0;
        GoalsFor = 0;
        GoalsAgainst = 0;
        GoalDifference = 0;
        Won = 0;
        Drawn = 0;
        Lost = 0;
        Points = 0;       
    }

    public String getTeamName(){

        return TeamName;
    }

    public String getShortName(){

        return ShortName;
    }

    public int getPlayed(){

        return Played;
    }

    public void getGoalsFor(int InsertGoalsFor){

        GoalsFor = InsertGoalsFor;
    }

    public void getGoalsAgainst(int InsertGoalsAgainst){

        GoalsAgainst = InsertGoalsAgainst;

    }

    public int getGoalDifference(){


        return (GoalsFor - GoalsAgainst);


    }

    public int getWon(){

        return Won;
    }

    public int getDrawn(){

        return Drawn;
    }

    public int getLost(){

        return Lost;

    }    

    public int getPoints(){

        return Points;

    }

    public void play(Match match){

        Played++;

        int GoalsFor = match.getHomeGoals(); 
        int goalsForThisMatch = match.getHomeGoals();
        int goalsAgainstThisMatch = match.getAwayGoals();
        String homeTeam = match.getHomeTeamName();
        String ShortName = match.getHomeTeamName();

        if (ShortName.equals(TeamName)){

           ShortName = homeTeam; 

        } else {

           ShortName = match.getAwayTeamName();  

        }

        if (goalsForThisMatch > goalsAgainstThisMatch){

            Won++;

        }  

        else if (goalsForThisMatch == goalsAgainstThisMatch){

            Drawn++;

        }

        else {

            Lost++;


        }   


    }

}
```

Comment: Code review item: many of your variable names don't follow [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) which makes your code more difficult to read. Please name variables starting with lowercase so that they don't appear to be class names.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem you're having is that the fields of your `Team` class are not being updated when you invoke the `play` method.

The reason you see this behavior is that you're defining local variables inside the `play` method that hide your class member variables:

```
public void play(Match match){
    ...
    int GoalsFor = match.getHomeGoals(); 
    int goalsForThisMatch = match.getHomeGoals();
    int goalsAgainstThisMatch = match.getAwayGoals();
    String homeTeam = match.getHomeTeamName();
    String ShortName = match.getHomeTeamName();
    ...
```

Your `GoalsFor` and `ShortName` local variables defined inside this method are hiding the class member variables you defined at the top of the class:

```
public class Team 

    private String TeamName;
    private String ShortName;
    private int Played;
    private int GoalsFor;
    ...
```